# how to display text on list view when click on the list view in android

Tags: android

i have list view which is generated from adapter it contain two images one when it is in normal form and one when the list view is click. my problem is that when click on list view the image will change but the text written on list view in normal form will not display on new image please help. 
thanks

Comment: This question is not well-written and, so far as I can tell, is nothing to do with R.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set [attr_android:duplicateParentState](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android%3aduplicateParentState) to true so your [TextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html) receive state changes from it's parent.